# Extract local max and min and Plot an envelope function

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, plotly

**My dataset:**

I have the following [dataset](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1dhi2CWXjYAu0WnvuERddHnDRz2D9Wd0N/view?usp=sharing) which when plotted using Plotly produces the following result (simplified):
[image: data points plotted time on x axis]

**My task:**

I want to create an envelope function that extracts the local maxima and minima from data from the above dataset and plots an envelope curve. It would roughly look like this:

[image: final result]

I have tried approaching the solutions provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48023982/pandas-finding-local-max-and-min) and the one for the envelope provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60402647/18384775). However, none of them works for me in this approach. For some strange reason, the scatter plots are producing the following [results](https://i.gyazo.com/39846df70243ba7752fea2922c145908.png) (for local min), which is not exactly what I need.

**Here's my code for the initial plot:**

```
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig= go.Figure()

fig.add_traces(go.Scatter(x= mem_df['time'], y=mem_df['volatge']))

fig.update_layout(xaxis_title = r'$\text{Time } T \text{ in s}  $',
                      yaxis_title = r'$\text{Deflection angle } \text{ in radians}$')
fig.update_layout(title= r'$\text{Deflection angles versus time for the damping sheet}$')
fig.show()
```

Any help, in this case, would be appreciated!
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your data contains a bit of noise. One possible approach is to find an appropriate curve fit, then find the local maximum and minimum on the fit. `scipy` comes to help:

```
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
from scipy.signal import argrelextrema

mem_df = pd.read_csv("path/to/file")
x = mem_df['time'].values
y = mem_df['deflection'].values
# dampened oscillator
func = lambda x, xi, k, phi, a, b: a * np.sin(k * x - phi) * np.exp(-xi * x) + b
popt, pcov = curve_fit(func, x, y)

fig= go.Figure()
fig.add_traces(go.Scatter(x=x, y=y, name="data"))

# plot the curve fit
xx = np.linspace(0, 20, 150)
yy = func(xx, *popt)
fig.add_traces(go.Scatter(x=xx, y=yy, name="fit"))

idx_max = argrelextrema(yy, np.greater)
idx_min = argrelextrema(yy, np.less)
fig.add_traces(go.Scatter(x=xx[idx_max], y=yy[idx_max], name="top"))
fig.add_traces(go.Scatter(x=xx[idx_min], y=yy[idx_min], name="bottom"))

fig.update_layout(xaxis_title = r'$\text{Time } T \text{ in s}  $',
                      yaxis_title = r'$\text{Deflection angle } \text{ in radians}$')
fig.update_layout(title= r'$\text{Deflection angles versus time for the damping sheet}$')
fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much for teaching me this! This is an interesting approach. I was wondering how to deal with the noise in the data.