# Fourier transformed audio data line to point graph using Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, audio, scipy, wave

I am working with multiple audio files and got the FFT of audio files and generated an audio spectrum, I got the algorithm from a YouTube video. I started this with 3 audio files but the results are confusing to handle and I hope there is a better way to handle it. This is the figure I have now.
[image: 3 audio files visualized]

The graph below is the graph I want ( I have colored the lines as it shows the max point at each frequency level. I have tried coding that but got many errors on it.

[image: The graph with desired lines]

The code that was used to generate one of the audio FFT graphs:

```
import scipy.io.wavfile as wavfile
import scipy.fftpack as fftpk
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
 
s_rate,signal=wavfile.read("audio_file")

FFT = abs(fftpk.fft(signal))
freqs= fftpk.fftfreq(len(FFT),(1.0/s_rate))
plt.plot(freqs[range(len(FFT)//2)],FFT[(range(len(FFT)//2))],color="orange")
```

What do you suggest on this topic?

Comment: Your question is likely to be closed again. Always provide a complete [mre] with code, **data, errors, current output, and expected output**, as **[formatted text](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)**. If relevant, only plot images are okay. Please see [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You need to provide sufficient data.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to obtain sound envelope using python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53470301/7758804)

Comment: Thanks. This is what I was looking for. Looks like I didn't know the term for it. Also thanks for the advice on asking better questions. I will try asking better questions next time.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to obtain sound envelope using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30889748/how-to-obtain-sound-envelope-using-python)