# How can I get the start and end indices of a note in a volume graph?

Tags: python, audio, frequency, volume, pyaudio

I am trying to make a program, that tells me when a note has been pressed.

I have the following notes exported as a `.wav` file *(The C Major Scale 4 times with different rhythms, dynamics and in different octaves)*:
[image]

I can get the volumes of my sound file using the following code:

```
from scipy.io import wavfile

def get_volume(file):
    sr, data = wavfile.read(file)

    if data.ndim > 1:
        data = data[:, 0]

    return data

volumes = get_volume("FILE")
```

Here are some information about the output:

```
Max: 27851
Min: -25664
Mean: -0.7569383391943734
A Sample from the array: [ -7987  -8615  -8983  -9107  -9019  -8750  -8324  -7752  -7033  -6156
  -5115  -3920  -2610  -1245    106   1377   2520   3515   4364   5077
   5659   6113   6441   6639   6708   6662   6518   6288   5962   5525
   4963   4265   3420   2418   1264    -27  -1429  -2901  -4388  -5814
  -7101  -8186  -9028  -9614  -9955 -10077 -10012  -9785  -9401  -8846]
```

And here is what I get when I plot the volumes array (x is the index, y is the volume):
[image]

I want to get the indices of the start and end of the notes like the ones in the image (Did it by hand not accurate):
[image]

When I looked at the data I realized, that it is a 1d array and I also noticed, that when a note gets louder or quiter it is not smooth. It is like a ZigZag, but there is still a trend. So basically I can't just get the gradients (slope) of each point. So I though about grouping notes into batches and getting the average gradient there and thus doing the calculations with it, like so:

```
def get_average_gradient(arr):
    # Calculates average gradient
    return sum([i - (sum(arr) / len(arr)) for i in arr]) / len(arr)


def get_note_start_end(arr_size, batch_size, arr):
    # Finds start and end indices
    ranges = []
    curr_range = [0]

    prev_slope = curr_slope = "NO SLOPE"
    has_ended = False

    for i, j in enumerate(arr):
        if j > 0:
            curr_slope = "INCREASING"
        elif j < 0:
            curr_slope = "DECREASING"
        else:
            curr_slope = "NO SLOPE"

        if prev_slope == "DECREASING" and not has_ended:
            if i == len(arr) - 1 or arr[i + 1] < 0:
                if curr_slope != "DECREASING":
                    curr_range.append((i + 1) * batch_size + batch_size)
                    ranges.append(curr_range)
                    curr_range = [(i + 1) * batch_size + batch_size + 1]
                    has_ended = True

        if has_ended and curr_slope == "INCREASING":
            has_ended = False

        prev_slope = curr_slope

    ranges[-1][-1] = arr_size - 1

    return ranges


def get_notes(batch_size, arr):
    # Gets the gradients of the batches
    out = []

    for i in range(0, len(arr), batch_size):
        if i + batch_size > len(arr):
            gradient = get_average_gradient(arr[i:])
        else:
            gradient = get_average_gradient(arr[i: i+batch_size])

        # print(gradient, i)
        out.append(gradient)

    return get_note_start_end(len(arr), batch_size, out)

notes = get_notes(128, volumes)
```

The problem with this is, that if the batch size is too small, then it returns the indices of small peaks, which aren't a note on their own. If the batch size is too big then the program misses the start and end indices.

I also tried to get the notes, by using the silence.
Here is the code I used:

```
from pydub import AudioSegment, silence

audio = intro = AudioSegment.from_wav("C - Major - Test.wav")
dBFS = audio.dBFS

notes = silence.detect_nonsilent(audio, min_silence_len=50, silence_thresh=dBFS-10)
```

This worked the best, but it still wasn't good enough. Here is what I got:
[image]

It some notes pretty well, but it wasn't able to identify notes accurately if the notes themselves didn't become very quite before a different one was played (Like in the second scale and in the fourth scale).

I have been thinking about this problem for days and I have basically tried most if not all of the good(?) ideas I had. I am new to analysing audio files. Maybe I am using the wrong data to do what I want to do. Maybe I need to use the frequency data (I tried getting it, but couldn't make sense of it)
Frequency code:

```
from scipy.fft import *
from scipy.io import wavfile
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def get_freq(file, start_time, end_time):
    sr, data = wavfile.read(file)

    if data.ndim > 1:
        data = data[:, 0]
    else:
        pass

    # Fourier Transform
    N = len(data)
    yf = rfft(data)
    xf = rfftfreq(N, 1 / sr)

    return xf, yf


FILE = "C - Major - Test.wav"

plt.plot(*get_freq(FILE, 0, 10))
plt.show()
```

And the frequency graph:
[image]

And here is the .wav file:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1CERH-eovu20uhGoV1_O3B2Ph-4-uXpiP/view?usp=sharing

Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: My caveman way to doing this would be to locate the minima along the envelope https://stackoverflow.com/a/53470301/6030926

Comment: For testing purpose, could you provide a link to the concerned wav file?

Comment: @Jib ok done. I sent the link of the file in google drive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

think this is what you need:
first you convert negative numbers into positive ones and smooth the line to eliminate noise, to find the lower peaks yo work with the negative values.

```
from scipy.io import wavfile
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.signal import find_peaks
import numpy as np
from scipy.signal import savgol_filter

def get_volume(file):
    sr, data = wavfile.read(file)
    if data.ndim > 1:
        data = data[:, 0]
    return data

v1 = abs(get_volume("test.wav"))
#Smooth the curve
volumes=savgol_filter(v1,10000 , 3)
lv=volumes*-1
#find peaks
peaks,_ = find_peaks(volumes,distance=8000,prominence=300)
lpeaks,_= find_peaks(lv,distance=8000,prominence=300)
# plot them
plt.plot(volumes)
plt.plot(peaks,volumes[peaks],"x")
plt.plot(lpeaks,volumes[lpeaks],"o")
plt.plot(np.zeros_like(volumes), "--", color="gray")
plt.show()
```

Plot with your test file, x marks the high peaks and o the lower peaks
[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. It worked pretty well. It is not 100% accurate and it sometimes makes mistakes, although it is expected. (Accuracy is probably 90%).

Comment: There are several parameter at the find _peak function , you can twist those to adjust the result. Your welcome

Answer (score 1):

This article presents two python libraries ([Aubio](https://aubio.org/), [librosa](https://librosa.org/doc/latest/index.html)) to achieve what you need and includes examples of how to use them: [How to Use Python to Detect Music Onsets](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/use-python-to-detect-music-onsets/) by [Lynn Zheng](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/author/lynn/)